# How to secure ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web Api Swagger with Login page?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

netcore 2.2 web api by the use of swagger is there any way that i can secure my api docs before user can see those api docs they would go to Login>then api Documentation.

more power stackoverflow. hope anyone can help..

Comment: @SajadAfaghiy this one is intended for Token Authentication not for login purposes

Comment: @eVolve nope what i meant is a login page not authorization for API

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a custom middleware to redirect to login if user is not authenticated when he would like to have an access to swagger index page:

```
public class SwaggerAuthorizedMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public SwaggerAuthorizedMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        //Add your condition
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/swagger")
            && !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/Identity/Account/Login");

            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        else
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }

    }
}
public static class SwaggerAuthorizeExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerAuthorized(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<SwaggerAuthorizedMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

In Startup Configure:

```
app.UseAuthentication();           

app.UseSwaggerAuthorized();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");

});
```

Comment: this saves me thanks

Comment: This helped a lot. i also configured OpenIdConnect in Startup.cs and used `await context.ChallengeAsync();` instead of redirect to login-page